# SQL sum of a group

Tags: sql

I need help getting the sum of a group in sql. This is the table that I have:

```
Sport         NumberOfPlayers
soccer          10
football        5
football        11 
baseball        6 
Tennis          8
```

This is what i want it to look like:

```
Sport         NumberOfPlayers      SumOfSport
soccer             10                 15 
football           5                  16
football           11                 16
baseball           6                  6
Tennis             8                  8
soccer             5                  15
```

Comment: Please show: how far have you gotten? What have you tried?

Comment: can you please tag the question with the RDBMS you are using if possible. There are syntactic differences between them.

Comment: Where's your query?

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You didn't specify your DBMS, so this is standard ANSI SQL using a window function to do this:

```
select Sport, 
       NumberOfPlayers, 
       sum(NumberOfPlayers) over (partition by sport) as SumOfSport
from the_table;
```

Answer (score 1):

Use an CROSS APPLY statement to perform an aggregation of the players on each row of the sports table grouped by sport, filtering the results of the CROSS APPLY using a WHERE clause to only return the aggregation of the first query if the sport in the OUTER APPLY is the same as that in the first query.

```
SELECT * FROM
(SELECT a.Sport, a.NumberOfPlayers FROM SportTable) as a

CROSS APPLY

(
SELECT Sum(b.NumberOfPlayers) as SumOfSport
FROM SportTable as b
WHERE a.Sport = b.Sport
GROUP BY b.Sport
) as b
```

Comment: How do you know Ozzy is using SQL Server?

Comment: How do you know that Ozzy isn't using SQL Server 2005 or 2008 which don't support window functions? (Except ranking window functions). He didn't specify, so I gave him an answer that will work in SQL Server.

Comment: Quote from the tag info for `sql`: "*Answers to questions tagged with SQL should use ISO/IEC standard SQL*". Window functions have been part of the SQL standard for nearly 15 years now. An answer with standard SQL will work on pretty much any [modern DBMS](http://modern-sql.com/)

Comment: Btw: SQL Server started to support window functions with SQL Server 2005

Answer (score 0):

Create a table that holds the total number of players for each sport and call it sumPlayer (or whatever you like). Then take your table join with sumPlayer.

```
CREATE TABLE sport(
    sport_name varchar(10),
    numberOfPlayers int
)

INSERT INTO sport (sport_name, numberOfPlayers)
VALUES ('soccer', 10),
('football', 5),
('football', 11),
('baseball', 6),
('Tennis', 8),
('soccer', 15)

SELECT sport.sport_name, sumPlayer.totalPlayer 
FROM sport LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT sport_name, SUM(numberOfPlayers) AS totalPlayer
    FROM sport
    GROUP BY sport_name ) sumPlayer ON sumPlayer.sport_name = sport.sport_name
```

then the result looks like this:

```
sport_name  numberOfPlayers
soccer      10
football    5
football    11
baseball    6
Tennis      8
soccer      5
```

Hope this helps, you should checkout the [`GROUP BY` statement](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_groupby.asp). In a very general sense if you are going to use aggregate functions such as (COUNT, MAX, MIN, SUM, AVG) then `GROUP BY` should be your first go to.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to do this is to Use a Temp Table #Temp0 to create the temporary structure that you want and then use another query to Update with the totals:

```
SELECT  [Sport]
        ,[numberOfPlayers]
        ,0 [SumOfSport]
  INTO #Temp0    
  FROM Table1      

Update #Temp0 
SET [SumOfSport] =
     (
     SELECT SUM(numberOfPlayers)
     FROM #Temp0 T1
     WHERE #Temp0.Sport = T1.sport 
     group BY Sport 
     )

SELECT * from   #Temp0 
DROP Table #Temp0
```

- Please Note (as pointed out by @a_horse_with_no_name ) This syntax is correct for T-SQL (MS). Other RDBMS may need some syntactic tweaking.

Comment: How do you know Ozzy is using SQL Server?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name (nice handle). I did notice your comment to your original question. I agree that it is legitimate to question The RDBMS when not specified, as syntax can/will vary. However, since the OzzyBenitez didn't respond. I figured I would post a alternative answer that would work in T-sql (MS) and is also conceptually correct and can be applied to other RDBMS with little tinkering.  Thank you for reminding me I will edit my answer to qualify it.